# Lenovo Thinkpad P51 4k support

Tags: thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, external-display

For my university, I am getting a Lenovo Thinkpad P51. And I would like to know if I would be able to use a 4K 27" monitor without blowing up the graphics card.

The monitor I am thinking of buying is the [AOC U2777PQU](http://aoc-europe.com/en/products/u2777pqu)

The specs of the P51 are:

**Processor**
Quadcore processor (7th Generation)
Intel® Core™ i7 - 7700HQ 
2.8Ghz, 6MB SmartCache
tot 3.8 Ghz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology

**Memory**

16GB DDR4 2400MHz Memory (2x 8GB)

**Display**

15,6-inch FHD with IPS-technology
1920x1080 resolution

**Graphicscard**

Intel® HD Graphics 630

Nvidia Quadro M1200 with dedicated 4GB GDDR5 memory
DirectX 12 (Shader Model 5.0) , OpenGL 4.4/4.5+, OpenCL 1.2

Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question, I hope you are able to answer it! If there is any information that could help to answer or clarify the question feel free to just ask it.

Yours sincerely,
Artos van Stel

Comment: Googled on Nvidia Quadro M1200  max resolution and it seems like it supports 4K. What do you want to do with the workstation? Lenovo has their workstations certified for e.g. Solidworks etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am mostly going to use it for Modelling (physics), text editing and some gaming (if there is time left over during my course).

Comment: The Intel GPU *may* cause problems (or it may not). I couldn't find info on whether it will handle 4K and it's possible that video outputs are actually driven by it, not NVIDIA card.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop will easily run 4K, at least so long as you connect it using DisplayPort (I recommend getting a docking station, simplifies things enormously).

4K was supported in Thinkpads since at least T430/X230 time using DisplayPort, though the oldest models had to run @ 30 Hz. The current generation, including P-series, work flawlessly at 60Hz

Comment: Would using a HDMI cable not suffice? Cause then I might need to buy a DisplayPort cable